# Unknown reason for gcc warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without cast

Tags: c, gcc, warnings

This is supposed to be compiled into a static library for homework. When I use the command: "gcc -c innoprompt.c inprompt.c" I recieve the warning and it points to the line "fin = openFilePrompt();" from innoprompt.c. I cannot see how this would cause this warning. Also, when I then compile the actual program with this library linked, I get the same warning. Due to the nature of the assignment, I am not allowed to change the file that is calling the functions from the library.

This is my header for the files.

```
#pragma once

#ifndef LIBINFILEUTIL_H
#define LIBINFILEUTIL_H

#include <stdio.h>

FILE* openInputFile(char* fileName);
FILE* openInputFile();

#endif
```

This is my inprompt.c
    #include "libinfileutil.h"

```
FILE* openFilePrompt(){
    char fileName[100];
    FILE* fin = NULL;
    do{
        printf("\nPlease enter file to be opened: ");
        fscanf(stdin,"%s",fileName);
        while(fgetc(stdin) !='\n');
        fin = fopen(fileName, "r");
        if(fin==NULL)
            printf("Failed to open file. Please try another file name.\n");
    }while(fin==NULL);
    return fin;
}
```

And lastly, this is my innoprompt.c

```
#include "libinfileutil.h"

FILE* openInputFile(char* fileName){
    FILE* fin = NULL;
    fin = fopen(fileName, "r");
        if(fin==NULL)
            fin = openFilePrompt();
    return fin;
}
```

Comment: There's no declaration for `openFilePrompt()` in `innoprompt.c` (or the files it includes) that lets the compiler know that the function returns a `FILE*`. So the compiler assumes that `openFilePrompt()` returns an `int`. Add the line `FILE* openFilePrompt(void);` to `libinfileutil.h`.  While you're at it, you should put a `void` inside the empty parens of the function declaration/prototype/definitions.

Comment: Note that this bug would have been detected if you didn't sloppily use `foo bar()` as if it were equivalent to `foo bar(void)`. They are not the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The header doesn't declare the function `openFilePrompt()`, so how is the compiler to know that it returns a pointer instead of an `int`?

As it stands, your header declares the same function twice, once with prototype, once without.  Maybe you should replace the second with:

```
FILE *openFilePrompt(void);
```

I'd then use the `void` in the function definition too for symmetry.
Note that in C (as opposed to C++), there is a big difference between that declaration and:

```
FILE *openFilePrompt();
```

This says 'the function `openFilePrompt()` exists, it returns a `FILE *`, but it takes an arbitrary (but fixed) number of arguments of unspecified type'.

Comment: Oh snap! Thanks! It was just total derp on my part. I was so sure that I had the right names, I didn't think to double check the function names.